# Could someone tell me what if anything is wrong with these translations?

Tags: translation

I'm just constructing a few sentences to test my comprehension of grammar. I'll make notes in my notebook about things so I don't forget them and hopefully end up with a properly constructed sentence.

> 私わ光の島住まう

and

> 私の理想わ余人勿れ裁く私の子等の為にヌードカラー寧ろの為にパーソナリティ

If they are so badly translated that you need to be told what the translation is I'll be happy to give the translation, however I'd rather leave them like this to see if the meaning can be extracted from the sentences.

Answer (score 2):

I could *extract* something out of those sentences, but it looks to me like you searched word for word (or used an online translation tool).

The topic marker is indeed pronounced "wa", but the hiragana is は. 私は, not 私わ

光の島住まう needs a に to indicate location. Also the verb is a bit odd maybe. I would have said 住んでいる instead.

Honestly, the second sentence is pretty much garbage to me. About my ideal, other people mustn't judge, for the sake of my children, nude color, rather for personality?

I'm myself guilty of trying too hard based on too little knowledge sometimes, but really, you should start with simpler sentences and follow a textbook first!